# Combine two Maps to a List of objects using Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given 2 Maps and an object

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> fruits = new HashMap<>();
fruits.put(1, Arrays.asList("apple", "banana"));
fruits.put(2, Arrays.asList("orange", "kiwi"));

Map<Integer, List<String>> veggies= new HashMap<>();
veggies.put(1, Arrays.asList("tomato", "potato"));
veggies.put(2, Arrays.asList("onion"));

Class Food
{
    private id;
    private List<String> fruitsList;
    private List<String> veggiesList;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to combine the given 2 maps to a single list containing Food object(List).

```
//Used for explanation purpose
Food food1 = new Food();
food1.setId(1);
food1.setFruitsList(Arrays.asList("apple", "banana"));
food1.setVeggiesList(Arrays.asList("tomato", "potato"));

//Used for explanation purpose
Food food2 = new Food();
food2.setId(2);
food2.setFruitsList(Arrays.asList("orange", "kiwi"));
food2.setVeggiesList(Arrays.asList("onion"));

//Wanted this list of food
List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList();
foodList.add(food1);
foodList.add(food2);
```

I need to get a List.
Can we achieve that using Java8 streams? 
Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Food> foodList = fruits.keySet().stream()
    .concat(veggies.keySet().stream())
    .distinct()
    .map(id -> {
        Food food = new Food();
        food.setId(id);
        food.setFruitsList(fruits.getOrDefault(id, new ArrayList<>()));
        food.setVeggiesList(veggies.getOrDefault(id, new ArrayList<>()));
        return food ;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If your `Food` class has a constructor taking the three parameters, it gets just a little more concise:

```
List<Food> foodList = fruits.keySet().stream()
    .concat(veggies.keySet().stream())
    .distinct()
    .map(id -> new Food(
        id,
        fruits.getOrDefault(id, new ArrayList<>()),
        veggies.getOrDefault(id, new ArrayList<>())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you *know* the ids are the same in both maps, you can skip the `.concat()` and `.distinct()` steps (which are quite expensive), and just use `get()` instead of `getOrDefault()`.

You can also (in any case) do

```
Set<Integer> allKeys = new HashSet<>(fruits.keySet());
allKeys.addAll(veggies.keySet());
List<Food> foodList = allKeys.stream()
    .map(/* as before */)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which is not quite a "pure stream" a solution, but is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two keys streams and use a distinct method to get only unique keys.

```
List<Food> foods = Stream.concat(fruits.keySet().stream() , veggies.keySet().stream())
                         .distinct()
                         .map(e -> new Food(e, fruits.get(e), veggies.get(e)))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```